# Why is scanf running taking my second input?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, scanf

Why is my scanf for my array running before the for loop? Output [enter image description here][1]

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int num,i,arr[10];
    printf("The number you want to add with each number is:");
    
   scanf("%d \n",&num);
   // printf("%d \n",num);
    
    printf("the 10 numbers are:\n");
    for(i=0;i<=9;i++){
        scanf("%d \n",&arr[i]);
    }
    printf("The new array is:");
    for(i=0;i<=9;i++){
        arr[i] = arr[i]+ num;
        printf("%d \n",arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: remove trailing whitespace (space, tab, newline, ...) from the scanf conversion: `scanf("%d", &num);` (for `"%d"` scanf already includes skipping optional leading whitespace, ie `scanf("%d", ...)` is the same as `scanf(" %d", ...)` or `scanf("\n\n\n%d", ...)`)

Comment: Never use trailing space in `scanf` conversion strings. Any and all kind of white-space in the string, including newline, will make `scanf` read all space so it can be ignored (thrown away). But to know when the spaces end, there must be some *non* space to read. Which is what causes the problem to happen.

Comment: Always check the return value (not the scanned value) of scanf(), it helps with debugging. You are ignoring it at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using trailing white spaces in your `scanf()` syntax. In addition, you are using `\n` in `scanf` and your `scanf` here is not only scanning the number `%d`, but scanning the whole thing in between quotations (" "). and that causes unexpected errors. So you should write your code in another way.